# Split Method for DoublyLinked List

Tags: java, data-structures

I am naive in programming, so i need help in data structures, i want to split a list and i have written the following piece of code, could any body please help me out to determine, is this right one. i would be grateful.

```
public Map<LinkedList, LinkedList> split(LinkedList list){

    int length = list.getSize();
    LinkedList list1 = new LinkedList();
    //LinkedList list2 = new LinkedList();
    //Node temp = end;
    for (int i=1; i<length/2; i++ )
    {
        list1.pushFront(list.popBack().getData());

    }
    Map<LinkedList, LinkedList> map = new HashMap<LinkedList, LinkedList>();
    map.put(this, list);
    map.put(this, list1);
    return map;

}
```

Comment: you are using the map wrong, read about maps

Answer (score 0):

First of all, a Map is a strange choice for the return type in your method, and you are using it in a strange way. I'd suggest a void method that accepts a reference to the source list and the two target split lists.

```
public void split (LinkedList source,LinkedList,target1,LinkedList target2)
{

}
```

Second of all, you should decide whether your method changes the source list or keeps it unaltered. Your current implementation removes half of the source list and adds it to the output list.

If that's your intent, you can have two parameters to your method, which would look like this :

```
public void split (LinkedList source,LinkedList,target)
{
    for (int i=1; i<length/2; i++ )
    {
        target.pushFront(source.popBack().getData());
    }
}
```

In this case you can alternately decide to create the new list inside the method and have the method return it, but that would be confusing, since the actual output is both the input list (which you modify) and the new list created by the method. That's why I think it's better not to return anything.

Comment: Isn't it better style, to always try to _return_ the actual return value than using the c-style supply of references to the target objects? A simple `Pair<LinkedList, LinkedList>` will do the job.

Comment: @ifLoop I guess that's a matter of opinion. Which Pair class are you referring too? I searched for Pair in my IDE and got several suggestions (android.util.Pair, sun.security.tools.Pair, etc...), none of them part of the JavaSE (or even JavaEE) packages.

Comment: Opinion based in a way, you are right, but more meaningfull to simply return the result instead of heaving to write a JavaDoc that explains that the objects referenced by the supplied arguments will be manipulated. I refer to the class [javafx.util.Pair](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/util/Pair.html) since JavaFX is part of the jdk since [7u6](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u6-relnotes-1729681.html). When working prior to this version, [java.util.Map.Entry](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) could be a choice.

Comment: @Eran you are right my intent is to modify the source list as it would take less space to do so, and if i wont return any list, then how may i be able to show the split lists,..? once again i am newbie to programming, so avoid if any silly thing goes by me.

Comment: @Asad You can pass the input list + an empty list to your method. The method will remove items from the input list and add them to the empty list. After the call to that method, both lists would contain a half of the original list.

Comment: @Eran can you give me any idea to implement append method for these split lists as well,..!!!!